# Merge multiple rows into one column

Tags: mysql, merge

I'm trying to merge different old values in one single column.
I have this table

```
id  code    langtype    desc        duration            
232 1104466 1           IT text     10
233 1104466 2           EN text     10
234 1104466 6           other desc  10
235 1104466 1           Other IT text(different row) 10
236 1104466 2           Other EN text(same row of previous) 10
```

And i would like to obtain a result like this

```
id  code    desc                                                duration
232 1104466 “IT” = “IT TEXT”, EN=”EN TEXT”, “ES”=”Other desc”   10
```

It is possibile is mysql?

Thank you

Comment: `select group_concat(concat(langtype, ' = ', desc)) from ... group by code`

Comment: @Rogach That seems like a valid answer. Please post it as such, so others can see this question has been answered (and perhaps elaborate a little bit).

Comment: I added some details because the example was incomplete

Comment: @devin - Now it is harder. How do you group the rows to be concatenated? I assumed by column `code`, but it is no longer the case after your update.

Comment: Yes =( That should be the desc string similarity but considering the different languages.

Comment: That's kinda hard - how can you compute similarity between strings in different languages?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Probably I have to move the problem to the application. 
Is it possible, instead, to obtain records with only one langtype inside? So without having 1,1,1,2 but three records "1,2","1","1"?

Comment: @Delayer - not sure I understood that. Can you give an example with some data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Something like this should achieve this effect:

```
select group_concat(concat(langtype, ' = ', desc))
from table
group by code
```

Here we first form a value to be extracted from each row (`concat(langtype, ' = ', desc)`) and then concatenate it for each grouped row (`group_concat`). You can change delimiters, or add quotes where you need - look at [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) docs.